# MySQL: Order, Limit, Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to program a solution where I have multiple linked tables.
Now I have another problem:

I want to limit count of returned lines to 1000.
But I want to show ID 1-1000, next page 1001-2000.
IDs may be stored in iregular order in database (ID 1 does not have to be the first row)

Not any problem so far:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1000
```

BUT
Now I have to sort resulty by another column:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1000
```

which might return other IDs than 1-1000
or I do

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC, ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1000
```

But this will only sort by ID an then by name. So if I would have any ID as duplicate (which is not possible) I would then have those sorted by name.

How can I achive that I get the first 1000 IDs (some IDs might not exist as they might have been deleted before!) and those thousand rows sorted by name?

Is that even possible?

Comment: Will subquery work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (
   SELECT ID FROM table ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0, 1000
) ORDER BY name ASC
```

As mentioned in comments that subquery is not supported, 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. Using JOINs is the only alternative left, like this:

```
SELECT table.* FROM tab JOIN (
   SELECT ID FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1000
) temp
ON table.ID = temp.ID
ORDER BY table.name
```

Comment: +1, and may I ask you question? I wonder if following query performs identically yours or differently. If differs from each other, which is faster? `SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM tab
        ORDER BY id ASC
        LIMIT 1000
    ) x INNER JOIN tab ON (x.id = tab.id)
    ORDER BY tab.name LIMIT 1000`

Comment: @InoSHeo it looks that your query would also return the same data. It uses JOIN instead of subquery. As for the performance, try both queries and check them using the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) statement which will give you the query execution plan. Generally JOINs are faster. You may also check [Join vs. sub-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query).

Comment: Aziz, Thanks. @FSEdarkalex If above two queries are what you want, Could you test both queries on your data? I want to know results with real data.

Comment: /* SQL Fehler (1235): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' */

so far for the subquery

//EDIT: And the join is wrking

Comment: @FSEdarkalex hmmm ... no option left other than trying the JOIN approach.